# How to handle "Cannot read property 'node' of null" in a query

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, apollo-client

I am pretty new to React/Gatsby and am doing a query with Apollo.
The thing is that if there is no title or image it'll say "Cannot read property 'node' of null". I get that because if I do not set a title or image in my headless CMS there's no data to read.

How can I make it conditional so that **if 'title' is empty don't render** it. Any other suggestions or tips about my code are always welcome!

Here's an example of my code

```
import React from "react"
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container"
import Image from "react-bootstrap/Image"
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client"

const APOLLO_QUERY = gql`
  {
    posts {
      nodes {
        title
        databaseId
        content(format: RENDERED)
        featuredImage {
          node {
            sourceUrl
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const ApolloTest = () => {

  const { data } = useQuery(APOLLO_QUERY)

  return (
    <Container>
      {data &&
        data.posts.nodes.map(post => {
          return (
            <article key={post.databaseId}>
              <h3>{post.title}</h3>
              <p>{post.content}</p>
              <Image
                src={post.featuredImage.node.sourceUrl}
                alt={post.title}
                style={{ width: "150px" }}
                fluid
              ></Image>
            </article>
          )
        })}
    </Container>
  )
}

export default ApolloTest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend *short-circuit evaluation* to first check if the information exists prior to trying to render it. A quick example is `{post.title && <h3>{post.title}</h3>}`, which will only render the `h3` and everything inside it if `post.title` is truthy. You can extend this to work for the image as well:

```
return (
  <Container>
    {data?.posts.nodes.map(post => {
      return (
        <article key={post.databaseId}>
          {post.title && <h3>{post.title}</h3>}
          <p>{post.content}</p>
          {post.featuredImage && <Image
            src={post.featuredImage.node.sourceUrl}
            alt={post.title}
            style={{ width: "150px" }}
            fluid
          />}
        </article>
      )
    })}
  </Container>
)
```